# How to clear GPU memory without 'kill pid'?

Tags: memory, gpu

I use my school's server for deep learning experiment. I stopped the python script but somehow the GPU memory was not released. I don't have the root to kill the processes, how can I clear the GPU memory?

[image: GPU memory usage]

I tried 'sudo kill -9' and 'nvidia-smi', but it said 'insufficient permissions' (I am using the university's server).

Comment: how was the memory allocated in the first place? CUDA? OpenCL? Vulkan?

Comment: CUDA ? I am not sure about it. I submitted the 'nvidia-smi' scrrenshot again.

Comment: The two word answer is that you can't. If you don't have root access to kill the processes, you certainly don't have the necessary access to do anything with the GPU or its driver. I fail to see a programming question here and have voted to close this as off-topic